# Recorrer foreach de video e imagenes

Tags: laravel

tengo este foreach ya hecho de imágenes que no quería modificar mucho la cuestio es que que en las distintas tarjetas que tengo quiero que se añada ahora una extra pero esa extra tiene formato video como podria recorrela igualmente con el codigo que tengo sin tener que realizar grandes modificaciones.

```
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($ultimostrabajo as $listado)
            <div class="col xl4 m6 s12">
                <div class="card sticky-action estilotarjeta">
                    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                        <div class="video-container">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QjkLM4z_I2E" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <img class="activator responsive-img"
                                 src="/storage/{{ $listado->url }}"
                                 alt="{{ $listado->name }}">
                    </div>
                    <div style="min-height: 120px;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;height: 100px;width: 100%;" class="card-content deep-purple lighten-2 z-depth-3">
                        <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-lighten-4">{{ $listado->titulo }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-reveal yellow accent-1"><span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">{{ $listado->titulo }}<i
                                class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                        <p>{{ $listado->descripcion }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, ¿los enlaces a esos videos vienen en la misma colección?, los conseguiste de otra consulta?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: sii estan en la misma coleccion, pero en la card solo puedo tener o imagenes o el video pero no ambas.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el criterio para determinar donde si deben haber imágenes y donde videos?

Comment: eso es lo que no tengo ese criterio, de ay mi problema, podria añadir un type en la coleccion que me distinga entre imagenes y videos, pero no se me ocurre nada en claro ni sencillito sin tener que hacer grandes cambios.

Comment: cuantas fuentes de archivos tienes?, es decir los videos son siempre `youtube` e imagenes `storage`, basta que uno sea del mismo patron se puede validar eso

Comment: solo esas dos tanto imagenes como videos podrian ser identificados asi perfectamente si.